# Problema ao renderizar imagem com React Native api wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, react-native

Fala galera beleza, estou fazendo testes extraindo dados de uma api wp utilizando React consigo extrair todos os dados porém a imagem não obtive sucesso, iniciei a pouco tempo com react

```
export default class App extends Component {

state={
    data:[],
  }



fetchData = async() =>{
  const response = await
  fetch('http://dominio.com.br/app/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');

  const posts = await response.json();

  this.setState({data:posts});

}  

componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
}  

render() {
    return (
     <View>


        <FlatList 
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem={({item})=><Postagens data={item} />}
            keyExtractor={(item, index)=> item.id}
            />


     </View>
    );
  }
}

class Postagens extends Component {


  render(){


    return(


      <View style={styles.posts}>


        <Image source={{uri:'this.props.data.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url'}} style={styles.imagem} />


        <Text>{this.props.data.title.rendered}</Text>


        <Text>{this.props.data.excerpt.rendered}</Text>


      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando a variável como string. Remova as aspas do valor do objeto que você aplica no URI do componente Image.

Ex.:

```
<Image source={{ uri: this.props.post.image }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema é que você está passando o valor como `string` e não `string template`, que é o acento crase ` .

```
<Image source={{uri: `${this.props.data.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url}`}}>
```

Porém não é necessário o uso desse formato, pois você está passando uma variável a uri. Então bastaria apenas o caminho:

```
<Image source={{uri: this.props.data.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url}}>
```

Espero ter ajudado